# Issue with lighting 15w bulb using raspberry pi & 8-pin relay

Tags: relay

Being naive to hardware & electronics, I might missing something silly here.

Here is my setup to able turn on/off bulb using iOS app and node.js as backend -

- Successfully setup raspberry pi 2
- Integrated 8-pin relay with pi (
  http://www.amazon.in/CHANNEL-ULN2803-CONTROLLABLE-RASPBERRY-ARDUINO/dp/B00LMX97UI/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1452686985&sr=1-1&keywords=raspberry+pi++relay)
- Having iOS app and working node.js backend, by which able to turn on/off led lights of relay
- Now connected 15w bulb with relay and external supply 
  (Referring :
  http://samanl33t.github.io/images/full_circuit.png

  &

  http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-JvsrMVRVE5g/Uich8ejNNjI/AAAAAAAAAYM/PP5wo0NEgbA/s1600/DSCN0402.JPG
- Still using iOS app able to turn on/off relay led lights but bulb is not being turn on/off.

Is any important thing missing here? or is there relay capacity issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[image: snapshot of setup 1]
[image: snapshot of setup 2]

Comment: Does the relay click when the indicator led lights up? Also the relay board in the amazon listing does not match the one in the pic.

Comment: Hello and welcome! The ULN2803 driver circuit (as in the first linked relay board) should work with 3V3 from the Pi. However the images show different relay boards and possibly different drivers, check those first. And please mind the potential dangers of electrocution when playing with mains voltages!

Comment: @SteveRobillard: Not actually, relay not making any click sound when lighten up. and yes in pic that is different relay.

Comment: Where are you getting the 12 V power for the relay?

Comment: @goldilocks: Actually currently relay is operated with pi only with 5v, do we require to give external supply to relay as well? but relay doesn't seem to have such supply pin. May be I have to dig much more on this.

Comment: Updated question with snapshots of setup.

Comment: You have 3 wires going from the pi to that relay -- ground, 3.3V *control*, and 5V *power*.  The last is connected to the *supply* pin on the relay, which is explicitly described as "*CONTROLLABLE* with 5V or 3.3V SIGNAL. *Power supply* : **12V** (Vcc)".

Comment: indeed 3 wires are : GPIO4 (yellow one),  5v power (black one), Ground (grey one).

Comment: What do you think *"Power supply : 12V (Vcc)"* means?  How much voltage have you supplied in relation to this?  The fact that it worked with a lower voltage connection does not matter.  The point is it does not work now.  I don't know enough about to relays to explain why, but I can read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34590/discussion-between-basha-and-goldilocks).

Comment: SAFETY FIRST! You're poking wires into a socket! And your Pi's ground wire is literally millimeters from mains! Just a public service announcement.